# Net Application Windows Mobile 6.0 cannot access webservice on IIS7.0 WS2008

Tags: compact-framework, windows-server-2008, windows-mobile-6

I have CFv2.0 VB.net application running on PDA 6.0 accessing webservices all the time for data exchange. Number of PDA's are more then 20 all accessing the webservice on Windows Server 2008 IIS7.0 all of a sudden some PDA's stop working (cannot access web service) and get web no connection exception. Can access the service from IE.

Any clue?

Cheers

Gauls

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @Chris: After changing to new PDA's the problem got better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing new PDA helped to improve connectivity